# how to write xml response using AFNetworking API

Tags: ios

I am working with AFNetworking API but i cannot find anything good with XML for iOS in it.

I want to download API XML response and write into file but using AFNetworking it is not possible because NSXMLDocument is not supported by iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case when you need just parse XML, try to use [KissXml](https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML) and DDXmlDocument class.
About [docs](https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML/wiki/Reference), kiss xml classes has the same intarface as the standart classes (NSXmlDocument)

Comment: Thanks, but i want to ask is kissxml can read response because i am not getting xml file.

Comment: DDXmlDocument has a few init methods – initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:
– initWithData:options:error:
– initWithRootElement:
– initWithXMLString:options:error:, you can init document with NSData, is this what you want? You can get your NSData from response